# VBA : Change the style of text when sending a mail

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, outlook-2007

I use Excel to send emails using text in a textbox as body. This works fine, except that when sending a mail, it only copies the text's font size, but not its color or style. I did lots of research, but didn't find any solution. Is there a code that allows Excel to copy the style of the text in a textbox as well as its content? Here is the code of sending the mail :

```
Sub SendMail()  
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

strbody = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mail").Shapes("txt").DrawingObject.Text
'I named the textbox "txt" in the worksheet
'On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "...@...com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Cells(3, 2)
    .Body = strbody

    .Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I know this is possible in HTML like :
`strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Good Morning;<p>We have completed our main aliasing process for today.  All assigned firms are complete.  Please feel free to respond with any questions.<p>Thank you.</BODY>"`
But since I'm writing the body in a textbox instead of in the code, I'd prefer to find a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PasteExcelTable is probably what you're looking for, but it's a little more hidden in the sense that Outlook is actually using a Word Document writer. You need to add the Word Object reference.

You'll have to modify the rest of your code to insert using the writer instead of .HTMLbody or .body.

Also note that for the inspector/write to work it seems that you cannot hide the window, but I did not fully test that.

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String

    Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim document As Word.document
    Dim oRng As Excel.Range

    Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With OutMail
        .To = "...@...com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Cells(3, 2)
        .Display
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector

        If olInsp.IsWordMail And olInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
            Set document = olInsp.WordEditor
            Set oRng = Range("A1:B2") ' The range you wish to copy into the document
            oRng.Copy ' Loads info to clipboard
            ' Write the range into the first paragragh of the word document.
            document.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, True

            ' Example how to write to the end of the email.
            Dim p As Word.Paragraph
            Set p = document.Paragraphs.Add
            p.Range.Text = "test"
        End If

    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice alternative way. Definitely easier that using a textbox and trying to convert that to HTML. I like this suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Cody G. I started using another method that I will post if I succeed. I will test yours right after.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't know of any default/built-in way in Excel to do this. What you need is a *Excel cell format to HTML converter*.

You can only built this on your own or find a suitable script online; similar to this one:
[Macro to Convert Excel Cell to HTML and preserve font formatting](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25022797/Macro-to-Convert-Excel-Cell-to-HTML-and-preserve-font-formatting.html).

Comment: Thank you. I looked into it. I put "test" into a cell and selected it before running the macro. But oddly nothing has happened.

Comment: This was not a "copy & paste that code" but more a suggestion how it could be done. There is no ready to use solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15582189)

Comment: @thebluefox this link was not meant to be the answer and I'm not willing to copy a full code without permission. This link is meant as an example that there is no 3 lines of code to do what *Francis* requested.

Comment: @Peh - Issue is though, if that link becomes invalid your answer becomes useless, as outlined here - [answer]. If this isn't meant to be an answer, it should have been a comment.

Comment: @thebluefox No, my answer, that there is no built in way and he needs to code his own *cell format to HTML converter* is still valid and this is my main message. The link is totally optional. If I had posted only the link and said here is your answer I would fully acknowledge. But here the answer still has useful information.

Comment: @Peh - I think it's a poor answer and I flagged it as such. The community will either agree or disagree.

Comment: @thebluefox that's ok, I totally agree with that. I know that this is not the best answer. But sometimes there is just no good answer to a question and I feel better to say: there is no easy way to do exactly what you tried and give a hint. Sometimes someone who shows you that you are on the wrong track helps more than nothing. A negative answer is still an answer. I won't hesitate to post an answer like: This won't gonna work, search for another approach and giving hits into a direction to search for a suitable solution. Nevertheless the community will decide ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Peh was trying to help, even though it didn't work out finally. But I still thank him for having given me a hint as noody had yet done. It helped :)