# Read email by subject, paste specific data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code that searches my Outlook inbox for a specific subject and pastes the entire body of the email into the first column.

Each email contains a table. I only want the table in Excel.

The table has 6 columns.

The body looks like:

```
ID     Type   LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME  DOC_TYPE    Doc_Description             
00000  test   DOE       John        0000        0000

Report : DocType
Report Source: IS reports
= 0000
```

```
Sub GetFromInbox()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items

olItms.Sort "Subject"

i = 1

lrow = 1

For Each olMail In olItms
    If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, "Test ") > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = olMail.Body
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next olMail

Set olFldr = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The output of `olMail.Body` is a string.

Comment: This answer I wrote might be helpful to you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899865/vba-change-the-style-of-text-when-sending-a-mail/42910966#42910966 --- particularly the method of accessing the writer (so you can get just the table ) --- otherwise, what does your `olMail.Body` look like?

Comment: Is the olMail.Body just a string of that text? Do you know how you want to parse it? --- Oh yes I forgot you can't comment until like 15 rep or something.

Comment: Well, in guessing what your answer might be --- "yes its a string" and "no I don't know how to parse it" --- generally tables have some sort of delimeter, such as a "\t" (tab) --- see "CSV" format. Unfortunately if you've got a string with spaces, it's very risky to interpret that because is a space really a new column? I.e. what if John was "Johnny Boy" --- if olMail.Body was an HTML body with a table, it would have tags and you'd need to learn how to parse that.

Comment: ID Type LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME DOC_TYPE Doc_Description
00000 test DOE John 0000 0000 : is in a table actually. I just want to take the tables from each email as is and essentially paste them one after the other each time it is generated. does that make sense?

Comment: I understand it's "in a table" but olMail.Body's output is... what exactly?

Comment: ahh yes its a string sorry

Comment: see olMail.HTMLBody and if it has a <table> tag, if so, use HTML parsing